# How do I take a collection of logos in SVG or PNG and make a Visio stencil collection automatically?

Tags: automation, visio

I'd like to turn the CNCF collection of logos into a Visio stencil collection. They provide both PNG and SVG formats. Because of the amount and that new ones are added regularly, I'd like to make this into simple process that can be triggered by a new release to the github project.

If I could even find something like the XML format of the stencil or whatever is behind it, I'd be able to iterate over the images and output the format.

What are my options for automating this stencil creation?

https://github.com/cncf/artwork

Answer (score 0):

Would you care to download and install my utilities for Visio:

https://www.paulherber.co.uk/visio-utilities3/

On the new **SuperUtils** ribbon choose **Stencil** -> **Create Stencil from Images**

This is a commercial offering but you have plenty of free uses.

It's not triggered by Github but just download the images and you are ready to go.